# Retrieving the name of a calling method's namespace

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces

How do you get the namespace of a method that has called the current public method?

I'm aware of how to find a calling method's name, but this is eluding me.

So here's an analogy of what I need for my Automated test solution in C#:

There are two cs files in "ExampleSolution.sln". Each of these class libraries has a single namespace. Namespace "1" and namespace "A".

Both namespaces have a single class and a single method.

Namespace 1 contains the method "LogIn", while Namespace A contains the method "MyTest".

MyTest calls LogIn at the start to perform a log in process. Inside of LogIn, code should determine the namespace of the calling method, MyTest. Therefore the string name of Namespace A should be returned as "A" to the LogIn method under Namespace 1.

The reason I want this is that the solution is structured in a way that valuable component information exists that can be used to determine a few variable's values without having to have these values passed in as arguments to the LogIn method each time it is called, which is hundreds of times.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "1" isn't a valid namespace name. It would be much more useful if you could *demonstrate* the problem with code rather than just describing it. What do you need to know the namespace for, by the way? This sounds like a design issue, to be honest.

Comment: Hi, I explained why I needed it in the original post. Also, those names were theoretical for the sake of the analogy.

Comment: Pressed enter before I was finished* - And I don't have any code to go by, yet. I would post it if I did though.

Comment: No, you didn't really explain why you needed it. You said you wanted to get the information without passing it as an argument - you didn't say why that's a good thing. Perhaps it would be better to centralize where you're calling the method, instead? Or have information somewhere in the current context? Just using the namespace of the class containing the calling method sounds brittle, unfriendly to tests, and generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh534540.aspx)

> By using Caller Info attributes, you can obtain information about the
>   caller to a method. You can obtain file path of the source code, the
>   line number in the source code, and the member name of the caller.
>   This information is helpful for tracing, debugging, and creating
>   diagnostic tools.

Assuming your folder structure maps to your namespacing, you can use `CallerFilePathAttribute` to get the namespace without having to use Reflection to get it.

Comment: That's awesome. Taking a look now. Will let you know if that gives me everything I need. Looks like it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ce0ktkk(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ce0ktkk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the current stack information. You can navigate to how far back you want to go in the call stack using "GetFrame", and use those results to get information about the caller, including its "Type", and then it's "Namespace".

Comment: Be aware that inlining can result in a different stack trace than you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to inspect the calling method's namespace. As Jon Skeet [once said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741215/retrieving-the-name-of-a-calling-methods-namespace#comment36496897_23741215):

> Just using the namespace of the class containing the calling method sounds brittle, unfriendly to tests, and generally a bad idea.

Instead, you might pass the data into your method. Keeping it contained within an object would let you keep the code clean, fast, and testable.

```
public interface IContext
{
    string SomeVariable { get; }
    int SomethingElse { get; }
}

public void LogIn(string user, IContext loginContext) { ... }


public class MyTestContext : IContext
{
    private MyTestContext() { }
    // TODO make this a singleton?
    public static MyTestContext Instance { get { return new MyTestContext(); } }
    public string SomeVariable { get { return "abc"; } }
    public int SomethingElse { get { return 2; } }
}
```